# Cryptic crossword clue: "Regularly clean and wet washing"

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

The answer to the clue is 'laundry', which is l-a-undry.

Where does the 'la' come from?

Source: The i's Five-Clue Cryptic, [12 April 2023](https://inews.co.uk/puzzles/five-clue/2023-04-12)

Comment: 'Undry' for 'wet' is groan-worthy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This interpretation relies on the word 'regularly'...

> In a cryptic clue, this usually suggests that you need to take letters from the word(s) preceding or following it *at regular intervals*. Most often this implies taking *every other letter*, either beginning with the first or the second letter of the word. (On other occasions it may be every third letter, or even higher...)
>
>  This is exactly what's happening here - taking 'clean' *regularly* (i.e. taking every other letter in the word) yields (-c)L(-e)A(-n) or _L_A_, which is the 'LA' you seek.